# jQuery ScrollTo: Multiple clicks on link = funky movement stacking

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Here is the code:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
        $(window).stop(true,true).scrollTo('+=800px', 1000, { axis:'x' } );
 });
$('.prev').click(function(){
        $(window).stop(true,true).scrollTo('-=800px', 1000, { axis:'x' } );
 });
```

Site can be previewed here: http://www.allisonnavon.com/index.php?/projects/raw-rhythm/

When the » are clicked more than once, it queues them up, even with the `stop(true,true)` parameter. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) only affects the animation queue for that element, instead you can just [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in this case (no need for the `scrollTo` plugin here):

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $("html, body").stop(true,true).animate({ scrollLeft: '+=800' }, 1000);
});
$('.prev').click(function(){
  $("html, body").stop(true,true).animate({ scrollLeft: '-=800' }, 1000);
});
```

This way the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) *will* effect the animation queue on those elements.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew you could `animate()` a scroll... that's pretty handy. In this case, I took out the "true, true" parameters because instead of just ignoring a second click while animating, it would automatically skip ahead to the next position and begin scrolling from there. I just made it `stop()` and it works perfectly. Thanks so much.